# Types plugin breaking because of server configuration

Tags: custom-post-types, mod-rewrite

I have tested this on three different hosts, using a number of different versions of both Types and WordPress, and I believe I've narrowed it down to my host (Firehost) setup, which they recently changed a bit.

Here are the modules they added (I believe) to Apache:

mod_deflate
mod_env
mod_expires
mod_headers
mod_mime
mod_rewrite
mod_setenvif

My issue is this: when I attempt to either add or edit a custom post type, I get to the point of pushing "Save Custom Post Type" ... and then I see a white screen, with a url similar to the following (stays the same as before I click the button, but displays a blank white page):

http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpcf-edit-type

It should be displaying something like this:

http://www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpcf-edit-type&wpcf-post-type=news&wpcf-rewrite=1

Has anyone had an issue like this before, or know what might be happening? I don't believe that the issue is within Types, WordPress, or a theme or plugin. I've tested this on more than 10 sites, and every site hosted on Firehost does exactly the same thing (nothing), and every site on Bluehost or GoDaddy hosting (similar sites with the same base theme and plugins, but varying versions of Types and WordPress, going back to just the last version of each), creates the post type correctly.

Please help! I'm in the middle of a project that has been shot to hell because I tried deleting and re-adding a post type before I was aware of the extent of the problem. I've now replicated the issue on a clean install with just the Types plugin installed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as `phpinfo();` will tell you a lot about the differences in the server configurations. I'd start there.

Comment: Good point. Is there anything in particular offhand you think I'd look for (obviously differences between the two, but any particulars)?

Comment: I don't know this particular plugin so I could only hazard a guess. But any difference would be a starting point.

Comment: Good deal. I'm having my server rolled back tonight to two days ago. Assuming the plugin works again at that point, I should be able to pinpoint differences. Is there a similar function which would show me installed Apache modules (I think that's correct terminology; I'm meaning mod_rewrite, among others).

Comment: If you are on a VPS just get a copy off httpd.conf